# Protractor Installation error

Tags: webdriver, protractor

I installed protractor (version 5.3.0) on windows 8.1 but when trying to execute the statement webdriver-manager update, I get the following response:
[image]
any help?

Comment: Can you open this url:  https://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/ in browser?  And did you need proxy to access public network?

Comment: Your web driver got updated and you should be good to run the latest updated webdriver version. It just promises rejection warning

Comment: @yong no I get access denied

Comment: webdriver-manager will access the url which will return a xml includes recent 10~15 latest versions of chromedriver, geckodriver. When you not specify version for chromedriver, geckodriver when execute `webdriver-manager update`, it will get the latest version form the xml to update.   How did you get the geckodriver-v0.21.0 installed if you never succeed to access that url.   If you can access before, get help from IT department to fix the network access issue (may be your network need proxy to access public network)